# how to distribute make builds to separate dirs from single makefile?

Tags: makefile

I have C sources in 'modules' directory. They are just *.c and corresponding *.h files. I have also 'tests' directory with test*.c programs used for testing modules. Finally I have have also some independent programs in 'progs' directory, and they have names expressed by *.c mask.

I would like to have a single main Makefile where I have commands to compile targets called 'modules', 'progs' and 'tests'. However, I have no idea how to define all dependencies in order to compile everything properly. My trials are not working.

Here is the simplest makefile which obviously do not work at all:

```
COMPILER=gcc
SOURCES=modules progs tests
CFLAGS=-O2 -g -Og -Wall -std=c14
INCLUDES= -Imodules -I. -I../modules         # no idea which is needed!
LFLAGS=-lm -lSDL -lSDL_image

all: modules tests progs

modules: modules/*.c modules/*.h
  ${COMPILER} ${CFLAGS} ${INCLUDES} -c $< -o $@

progs: progs/*.c
  ${COMPILER} ${CFLAGS} ${INCLUDES} -c $< -o $@ ${LFLAGS}

tests: tests/*.c
  ${COMPILER} ${CFLAGS} ${INCLUDES} -c $< -o $@ ${LFLAGS}

#%.o: %.c   # no idea how to force compiling to modules OR progs, etc.
```

I have heard about CPP and auto-creating dependencies for modules, but nothing I've tried is working, even after trying gnumakefile help examples or other manuals. My case is somehow different :(

Comment: Do you mean the C PreProcessor? In case you mean C++: that is a different language. Read [ask], your question is too broad and opinionated as asked.

Comment: Where do you want the object files (`foo.o`) and executables to go?

Comment: Have a look at my tamplate library for GNU make, it allows to achieve what you need. Here is the tutorial on basics: https://github.com/igagis/prorab/blob/master/wiki/TutorialBasicConcepts.md and also there is an example project which shows how to organize building of several directories from root makefile: https://github.com/igagis/prorab/tree/master/examples

Comment: I understand that my question is not very well formatted and asked, sorry for possible confusion. Simply put, I would like to have a single directory with Makefile and few subdirectories: tests, src, utils. In tests and utils directory I have some *.c programs, in src directory I have *.c modules and their compartments/headers *.h. All is in C-language, but compiled with gcc. I would like to have *.o files in every directory, as well as executables in tests and utils, but done with only one main Makefile. Right now I split everything to four Makefiles.

Comment: Igagis, thank you for the suggestion, but I think I don't need so sophisticated tool you've created. However, I looked into the sources of makefile.mk and I appreciate your skills and effort to create a real programming language using makefiles! :)

Comment: @piotao thanks for feedback. What's wrong with your current approach? What is the reason you want to have everything in single makefile? Any use cases you can't achieve right now? Of course, it is possible to have it in single makefile and it is not that difficult, but requires some typing, so unlikely somebody here will write the makefile for you. But everybody here will be glad to help you with principal problems you may have, like the questions I asked above, and suggest the right, correct and reasonable solution :).

Comment: Thank you. I think that right now I can stick to the simple solution which works because each directory has it's own makefile, with custom settings. This is maybe recommended or at least easier to setup. According your makefiles (which are crazy!) it may be some day when I return to them and analyze/use them better.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this solution, which I found few days ago, will/could work:

Directories I have are 'src', 'tests', and 'utils'. The global Makefile, looks like the following:

```
DIRS = src tests utils

all:
        make -C src -f Makefile
        make -C tests -f Makefile
        make -C utils -f Makefile

clean:
        make -C src -f Makefile clean
        make -C tests -f Makefile clean
        make -C utils -f Makefile clean

.PHONY: all clean ${DIRS}
```

This works, although I would rather prefer some automated solution for iterating over all dirs from ${DIRS}. For only three of them, it's OK for me to type commands three times.
Then, in each directory, its own Makefile exists:

In src:

```
SOURCES = ${wildcard *.c}
HEADERS = ${SOURCES:.c=.h}
OBJECTS = ${SOURCES:.c=.o}
DEPENDS = ${OBJECTS:.o=.d}
INCLUDE = -I/usr/include/SDL

LDFLAGS = -lm -lSDL -lSDL_image
CCFLAGS = -O2 -g -Wall -pedantic ${INCLUDE}

all: ${OBJECTS}

-include ${DEPENDS}

%.d: %.c
        ${CPP} ${CCFLAGS} $< -MM -MT ${@:.d=.o} >$@

%.o: %.c
        ${CC} ${CCFLAGS} -c $< -o $@

clean:
        rm -f ${OBJECTS} ${DEPENDS}

.PHONY: clean all
```

Then, in tests and utils (they are very similar):

```
SOURCES = ${wildcard *.c}
OBJECTS = ${SOURCES:.c=.o}
DEPENDS = ${OBJECTS:.o=.d}
PROGRAM = ${patsubst %.c,%,${wildcard test*.c}}
INCLUDE = -I/usr/include/SDL -I../src

LDFLAGS = -lm -lSDL -lSDL_image
CCFLAGS = -O2 -g -Wall -pedantic ${INCLUDE}

all: ${PROGRAM}

test%: test%.o
        ${CC} ${CCFLAGS} $+ ../src/*.o -o $@ ${LDFLAGS}

#-include ${DEPENDS}

#%.d: %.c
#       ${CPP} ${CCFLAGS} $< -MM -MT ${@:.d=.o} >$@

%.o: %.c
        ${CC} ${CCFLAGS} -c $< -o $@

clean:
        rm -f ${PROGRAM} ${OBJECTS} ${DEPENDS}

.PHONY: clean all
```

and in 'utils' I have:

```
SOURCES = ${wildcard *.c}
OBJECTS = ${SOURCES:.c=.o}
DEPENDS = ${OBJECTS:.o=.d}
PROGRAM = ${SOURCES:.c=}
INCLUDE = -I/usr/include/SDL -I../src

LDFLAGS = -lm -lSDL -lSDL_image
CCFLAGS = -O2 -g -Wall -pedantic ${INCLUDE}

all: calcVariance getScanLine

calcVariance: calcVariance.c
        ${CC} ${CCFLAGS} $< ../src/*.o -o $@ ${LDFLAGS}

getScanLine: getScanLine.c
        ${CC} ${CCFLAGS} $< ../src/*.o -o $@ ${LDFLAGS}

%.d: %.c
        ${CPP} ${CCFLAGS} $< -MM -MT ${@:.d=.o} >$@

%.o: %.c
        ${CC} ${CCFLAGS} -c $< -o $@

clean:
        rm -f ${PROGRAM} ${OBJECTS} ${DEPENDS}

-include ${DEPENDS}

.PHONY: clean all
```

Again, I did not found anything nice to iterate over all programs from ${SOURCES}, because some dependencies were not calculated properly, and because of that I defined and put verbatim program names into rules. Maybe somebody will have some clue how to do that better. Also, I learned that using preprocessor to automatically determine all dependencies is a pretty nice trick, which in turn makes all makefiles lot better, automated and precise.

Drawbacks:
1. Some lack of automation, especially in 'utils' (my automated obvious version fooled make and it tried to build calcVariance with getScanLine.o object file, which failed miserably.

2. Make is not seeing new rebuilded objects from ../src/*.o files after rebuilding them from 'src' dir. Nothing changed is seen, when I try to build from 'tests' or 'utils', after I rebuilt 'src'. I have to force clean and then make all to rebuild those directories.
3. I have the feeling that this solution is not the best I could achieve due to my lack of understanding how make is working. So, I think lot's of things could be improved. Any comments are very welcome.